# How does this NoSQL injection work?

Tags: sql-injection, nosql

Could someone explain what this is doing and how it works? I already know about SQL injection but the NoSQL is confusing.

This is a lecture slide from my professor but he provides very little context.

[image]

Comment: What about the slide do you understand? That will help us to understand how to answer.

Comment: What exactly confuses you? What do you understand so far and what do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

In Mongo JSON objects (I will call here them this way, in fact they are a restricted subset of JS `object`s and correspond more to python `dict`s. Also note that in Mongo Wire Protocol BSON is used, which is a binary superset of JSON, though not very efficient) are used as a part of query language. In PHP there exists a type `array` which maps to both JSON [objects](https://ideone.com/yjIpoz) and [arrays](https://ideone.com/Bx3ryO). So when you are populating a PHP array with values iteratively, unless special care is taken you can never be sure if it will result into JSON array or an object. In MongoDB JSON objects are used to specify conditions.

It is also often assummed by some webmasters that it is not possible to pass arrays via request parameters in PHP.

In your example an imagionary webmaster assummed that that arrays cannot be passed via request params, so there were no sanitization, the type was not checked. An adversary has managed to pass a PHP array, which has been serialized into a JSON object.. I don't know whether `"<some name>":{ $eq: <some value> }` is more secure than `"<some name>": <some value>`, the docs says they are the same, but IDK if they are really the same.

So before processing untrusted data withncore of your system you should always verify and sanitize them.